Ubuntu 20.04 (NICE DCV) mic audio quality very inconsistent
So I have this EC2 g4dn.xlarge instance set with NICE DCV and Ubuntu 20.04(it uses uses custom Intel Cascade Lake CPUs and NVIDIA T4 GPUs), I'm running Minecraft on it with a simple voice chat plugin. The audio through the mic is fine most of the time, but around 5% of the time, it just goes all muffled, sounds like talking through a wall and is very unclear. And there are some crackling occasionally as well. I made sure this is not simple voice chat or Minecraft's problem as I also set up OBS to record my mic input, and the quality is still dropping a lot at some point(it becomes normal after a while).
Anyway, I did a lot of searching myself, first I thought this was the CPU usage problem because Minecraft is a very CPU-consuming game, so I tweaked Minecraft to use as little CPU as possible(mods and reducing rendering distance, etc) and I set very high priority for PulseAudio (as some suggested, nice to -20 and real-time priority to like 90), I also tried tweaking the settings in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf in various ways but none of the above attempts help completely eliminate this problem.
So I'm wondering if any of you have gotten the same problem before and how you fixed it? Is this really a Ubuntu issue, or could this be a Nice dcv issue (they use a virtual sound card, and I couldn't find any post related to the NICE dcv audio issue)?  I'd really appreciate any help at this moment, thanks.

You suggest it could be a hardware issue but failed to add the hardware info to the question. Please edit the question and add this info.

So aws g4dn instance uses custom Intel Cascade Lake CPUs and NVIDIA T4 GPUs. I don't know what exactly the sound card is, they just said it's a virtual one.
